# How can I solve // Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter, helper

Is there someone who encounters this problem

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not download kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.8.21-gradle76.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.8.21)
> > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.8.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.8.21-gradle76.jar'.
> > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-gradle-plugin/1.8.21/kotlin-gradle-plugin-1.8.21-gradle76.jar'.
> > jcenter.bintray.com
> ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

just knew that my flutter is quite installed is set
"flutter doctor detects everything is norma l" ...

Comment: Try deleting the 'android' directory, then using `flutter create . --platforms=android` to recreate it. Note that any customization you've done will be lost.